# Should I say "study materials" or "education materials" or "teaching material?"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I am building a web application where people can upload their study materials about robotics and programming and manage them and share etc.

I want to name it well, so at the moment I have:

> Information system for **study materials** of robotics and programming

Is this phrase grammatical? Does it sound idiomatic? If not, would these fit the context better:

- education materials
- teaching material

Comment: "Information system for study materials ..." -> "Web application for study of robotics and programming"

Answer (score 3):

*Study materials* and *teaching materials* are two different things.  One uses *study materials* to study, whereas *teaching materials* are used to teach.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Robotics and programming documents/resource sharing system.

Answer (score 0):

The word material is used here meaning:

> the things that are used for making or doing something ([LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/material_1))

In this sense, dictionaries list it both as **uncountable => material** and **countable, plural => materials**. So, all three examples are grammatically correct.

[ODO Advanced Learner's dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/material) gives examples that are closest to your intended use:

> [countable, usually plural, uncountable] things that are needed in order to do a particular activity
>
> - *teaching materials*
> - *The company produces its own training material.*

---

As for the choice between "study", "teaching" and "education" per definition you should decide what is the purpose of the material, i.e. what activity would be performed using it - the name of the activity should precede either *material* or *materials* (whichever you chose).

From your example it is clear that this material is for students, not teachers. So, even though it might be argued that one student is *teaching* the other using this material, or that the material servers an *educational* purpose, the end goal of posting the material is for students to use it for *studying*. I agree with Ahmed on this; **study material(s)** would be my choice as well.